# Transition an image object between pages in Ionic 2 application

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to transition a DOM image object from one screen to another. i.e. I don't want the image object to disappear and then re-appear in DOM rather somehow make my image fixed with the background sliding beneath it. Like a parallex sort of animation effect. Can it be done with the regular way of loading a new page in the navigation control stack with

```
navCtrl.push('page2', { id : 5, category : 'phone' });
```

or do I have to implement a slider component for all my pages? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your page like Angular 4, just using components and not a new page.

put your img in root page and change just parts of the page using components, this way your can't push a page, use router.

I'm don't know if will work 100%, but you can try.